# How can I create a truly responsive design with button and text?

Tags: flutter, dart, responsive-design

I have not been able to figure out how to fix the size of the button as i drag and resize the app , all other widgets work fine but buttons will give an overflow error, also please do advice, i know its an issue with the button height, i want to make the text smaller as i resize it to small. also, if there is another way of making the app responsive ? i.e for all mobile size and screen including web and ipads ?

please help me update my code,  this is my code so far: In general i want an answer as well an advice as how to approach a responsive design?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return OrientationBuilder(builder: (context, orientation) {
      final isLandscape = orientation == Orientation.landscape;
      return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      ButtonFlightPlanWindow(text: 'Procedures', fn: procedure),
                      ButtonFlightPlanWindow(text: 'Procedure', fn: procedure),
                      ButtonFlightPlanWindow(text: 'Procedu', fn: procedure),
                      ButtonFlightPlanWindow(text: 'Pro', fn: procedure),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.58,
                  height: screenHeight * 0.3,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      const Center(
                        child: Text(
                          "Routes",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.58,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )),
      );
    });
  }

  void procedure() {}
}

class ButtonFlightPlanWindow extends StatelessWidget {
  String text;
  void Function() fn;

  ButtonFlightPlanWindow({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    required this.fn,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final buttonWidth = screenWidth < 500 ? screenWidth * 0.8 : 200.0;
    return SizedBox(
      width: buttonWidth,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
            const Color.fromARGB(255, 62, 84, 122),
          ),
        ),
        onPressed: fn,
        child: Text(text),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe that your button is not respecting your changes to its height/width because it is inside a container, so it has the constraints coming up from its parent(the container). This container has a width of "width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1", but your button has a width screenWidth * 0.8 or 200. Try changing the size definitions in the container that the buttons are inside.

Also in relate of the responsive flutter design, you are doing well, always try to use mediaQuery or other ways to dinamically get the sizes of your widgets, this will let your widget proportions be fine on almost every cellphone.